# Inserting empty string as NULL to MySQL on Mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, mysql

I run into a strange problem. I tried to run the following statementon Mac:

```
INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('')
```

where field is numeric that accepts `NULL` value.

I have a MySQL 5.5.40 installed on Ubuntu, where this query runs nicely. I also have a MySQL 5.5.45 installed on Mac where the query fails:

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'field'

I found that standard MySQL install on Mac use standard values and doesn't use any `my.cnf` config file. I tried to examine `my.cnf` on Ubuntu but none of the config options seemed related to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution is not to use strict mode in my.cnf:

original:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

modified:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the error message eligible: you can't insert a string into an int column.
Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (NULL)
```

or simple

```
INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ()
```

Comment: It depends on server configuration. Check my own answer. I made tests, it works.